# How can I be certain that this infinite product has no associated value?

Tags: infinite-product

I have a product

$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}{\ln{n}}$

which fails the standard test for convergence with

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\ln(\ln(x))}$

not converging. However, I am aware that that other seemingly divergent sums have associated values, such as the sum of all natural numbers, which comes from the Riemann zeta function. So how can I be sure that this indeed diverges?

As a side note, I noticed that the partial sums

$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{k}{\ln(\ln(x))}$

appear to be converging on a line with the slope probably between $1<m<2$. I haven't been able to check this for very very large values, but it seems to hold true for the partial sums atleast $k < 2000$

Edit:

It recently came to my attention that I may be able assign a value with the zeta function by using the sum above, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am aware that that other seemingly divergent sums have associated values, such as the sum of all natural numbers, which comes from the Riemann zeta function. So how can I be sure that this indeed diverges?

Seeing how you understand that the sum diverges (as per usual definition) and at the same time ask if it "indeed diverges", I interpret the latter as a new term you implicitly introduce where "sum X indeed diverges" means "sum X can't have a value associated with it one way or another".

But if we interpret the question this way, no, you can't be sure: even if the product "indeed diverges" now, there is a chance that someone later will invent some other way to associate a value with it. Basically, predicate "X indeed diverges" is ill-defined.

Comment: What ? When associating a finite value to a divergent series, it doesn't affect that the series doesn't converge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series

Comment: @user1952009 OP asks not if the series in question converges or not but if it "has no associated value" (at least in the title), with implicit statement that a series which diverges but can be assigned such a value doesn't "indeed diverge". At least that's how I see the question.

Comment: You are wrong, as I said assigning a finite value to a divergent series doesn't affect that the original series doesn't converge

Comment: @user1952009 "assigning a finite value to a divergent series doesn't affect that the original series doesn't converge" - I completely agree with that and never stated otherwise.

Comment: You did with "X indeed diverges". Again, that the product diverges has a precise meaning and it won't change when assigning a finite value to it

Comment: @user1952009 I interpret "indeed diverges" (note the quotes) as a new term OP implicitly introduced. Edited my answer to clearly state this.

Comment: Yes, please excuse my poor word choice. I understand the sum diverges, and that even sums like the sum of all natural numbers diverges but does have a defined associated value. I'm no mathematician.

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ge 3$, $\ln n > 1$. So $\Pi_{n=3}^{+ \infty} \ln n$ is the product of positive numbers greater than 1 and hence it must diverge.

Comment: That condition is not enough to ensure divergence! For example, $\Pi_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+2^{-n})$ is a product of positive numbers greater than 1 and [it converges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+from+n%3D0+to+infinity+of+(1%2B2%5E(-n))).

Comment: @pregunton good point; I should have added that $\ln n$ is increasing in $n$.

Comment: that $\ln n > 2$ for  $n > 20$

Comment: @ user1952009 28: and that nails it down.